# DB2 Dynamic View CREATE statement from SYS tables

Tags: sql, db2-luw

Uncertain if this is even possible, but here goes...

In DB2 v9.7, I'm trying to create a view for every table in a schema.

The view should contain each column, but appends one more timestamp column.

i.e. 
TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3)

V_TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3, INS_DTTM)

TABLE2 (COL1, COL4)

V_TABLE2 (COL1, COL4, INS_DTTM)

Here's what I've got so far

```
SELECT 'CREATE VIEW V_' || NAME || ' (' || 
(SELECT LISTAGG(NAME, ', ') FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS WHERE TBCREATOR=CREATOR)  || ') 
AS SELECT  ' || (SELECT LISTAGG(NAME, ', ') 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS WHERE TBCREATOR='SCHEMA') || ', CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP) 
AS INS_DTTM FROM ' || CREATOR || '.' || NAME
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
WHERE CREATOR = 'SCHEMA' AND NAME LIKE 'T%' ORDER BY NAME;
```

It's my subselect that is causing me grief...

I get the following:

```
CREATE VIEW V_TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3) AS SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP) AS INS_DTTM FROM SCHEMA.TABLE1
CREATE VIEW V_TABLE2 (COL1, COL2, COL3) AS SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP) AS INS_DTTM FROM SCHEMA.TABLE2
```

I'll apologize in advance if my syntax is off...I'm retyping across development environs and the internet...so I'm certain I've made mistakes...

I want the columns listed to relate to the table name of that row...but the LISTAGG appears for just the first row...

Hope this makes sense...and if anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused.  What is it you're trying to accomplish by creating views of every table?  It seems like a great way to make sure the query engine can't optimize your queries very easily.  If you're trying to make the DB read-only for certain users, [create a role and grant only select permissions to the role](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68410/create-new-read-only-user-on-db2-on-the-whole-database) and then assign a user to that role.

Comment: By inserting the 'fake' column in the view, the next mart or DBMS that the data moves to with our ETL tool will update that column based on it's internal clock...some of our destination systems clock are'off'...this way the INS_DTTM is correct for the system it lands on.

Comment: If you "_want the columns listed to relate to the table name of that row_" then you probably should add that condition to the `WHERE` clause of the subselects, no?